# cannot delete file with rm -rf

Tags: linux, ubuntu

While trying to delete a directory with "rm -rf", I kept getting "directory not empty". Puzzled, I looked why and I seem to have a "zombie" file stuck in there. I have no idea how to delete it. Is fdisk my only solution?

```
# rm -rf noc
rm: cannot remove directory `noc/INBOX/#msgs': Directory not empty

# rm -rf noc/INBOX/#msgs/000201E5.eml 

# rm -rf noc
rm: cannot remove directory `noc/INBOX/#msgs': Directory not empty

# rm  noc/INBOX/#msgs/000201E5.eml 
rm: cannot remove `noc/INBOX/#msgs/000201E5.eml': No such file or directory

# cd noc/INBOX/#msgs/
# ls -la
ls: cannot access 000201E5.eml: No such file or directory
total 2248
drwx------ 2 root root 2293760 2013-08-27 21:55 .
drwx------ 3 root root    4096 2013-08-27 21:55 ..
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?                ? 000201E5.eml

# ls -iN | cat -A
6346412 000201E5.eml$

# find . -inum 6346412 -exec rm -i {} \;
find: `./000201E5.eml': No such file or directory

# unlink 000201E5.eml 
unlink: cannot unlink `000201E5.eml': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you checked for filesystem corruption using `fsck`?

Comment: Can you `mv` the offending file somewhere else? That doesn't solve the problem, but it would at least get it out of your way.

Comment: You can use `clri` and *then* run fsck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **should** start by unmounting and using `fsck` to check the filesystem for corruption.

If that does not repair it, then you can try examining the filesystem manually.

The `unlink` command simply calls the system `unlink()` function. Since it returns the error `No such file or directory`, you can start by looking at exactly what the struct of the directory says about the file.

`ls` uses the `readdir()` call, and returns an error trying to read the dir entry. You would have to use the `getdents()` call directly to read the dir. Luckily there is a complete example in `man 2 getdents` which you can compile and use without needing to modify anything.